# Python: function for sumation of unlimited raw_inputs

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

I am stuck on the simple things, but I cannot sleep well until i will solve this.

So my idea was, to:

1. make the list of raw_inputs as long as the desired letter is typed-in (e.g. x)
2. make a function with undefined length variable (using *args)
3. make a summation variables (parsed arguments)

Challenges:

1. Making a loop for the symbol validation
2. Making a list of raw_inputs using append (or extend), but not include the last symbol x to the list
3. Forwarding the correct type arguments to the function
4. Mystery how to make a summation if my arguments sits as a packed
   tuple (*args)?

E.g. If I make an input list using append, in summation I recieve:

> k = sum(args) #works if list of (rgs can be readed as ints or strs
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Some code:

```
def autosum(*args):
k = sum(args) #works if list of (rgs can be readed as ints or strs
print "Your sum", k
return

print ("Type integer or x to close")


input_list = list()
while True:
    rawinputvalue = raw_input(">>")
    input_list = rawinputvalue
    if type(rawinputvalue) != "x":
        break
    input_list.append(rawinputvalue)

autosum(input_list)
```

These are the very basics how to operate with different types of arguments, also some use of functions. So hope, other could learn from this too, thanks.
Don

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is this supposed to be a tutorial or an actual question?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the most important part, how do I solve my error?
And what are the tips coming through the challenges?

Comment: can u show your error..??

Comment: Hint: you can add another integer to an already known sum. You don't need an explicit _list_. If you need a _sequence_ of unlimited length, you should [read about generators](http://intermediatepythonista.com/python-generators).

Comment: Error is showed in yellow window. Ill check the generators stuff. Thanks. Seems like a function cant accept arguments and forward them to summing.

Comment: Seems like there are quite a few problems here, but what might help is to remember that inputs are treated as strings.  The error you are getting is quite common when asking for integer inputs.  You need to convert the inputs to integers.  int(raw_input(">>"))

Comment: raw input basically returns a string and hence you have to convert it into an int before precessing like `input_list.append(int(rawinputvalue))` if not you can also use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` !

Comment: I think this place: k = sum(args): brings tuple